# Converting lat/lon to x/y in matplotlib for imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Really dumb question.  I have a global gridded data set that I would like to subset to a certain lat/lon range (50N-80N, 185E-230E) and place it in mercator projection.  Since I'm using imshow I need to get the extent set correctly.  I can't find an example of what I need.  I obviously don't understand how to set this up.  Any help appreciated.

```
mapproj = Basemap(projection = 'merc', resolution = 'l', lat_0=65,lon_0=207.5)

x0, y0 = mapproj(185.0,50.0)
x1, y1 = mapproj(230.0,80.0)

myplot = plt.imshow(datamasked.T, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = my_cmap, \
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0.0, vmax = 10.0, clip = False), \
extent = (x0, x1, y0, y1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks good, the only thing is that you need to use basemaps `imshow` method. That is, instead of `plt.imshow()` you should use `mapproj.imshow()`

Here is a complete working example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-10,llcrnrlat=35,urcrnrlon=35,urcrnrlat=60.,
             resolution='i', projection='tmerc', lat_0 = 48.9, lon_0 = 15.3)

m.drawcoastlines()

#Madrid
x,y = m([-3.703889],[40.4125])
m.plot(x,y, marker="o", color="blue", label="Madrid", ls="")

# image background
x0, y0 = m(-10, 35)
x1, y1 = m(35, 60)
extent= (x0, y0, x1, y1) # lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax
m.imshow(np.random.rand(23,56), interpolation = 'nearest',
          extent = extent, alpha=0.4, cmap="terrain")


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The data set I read in is actually global, and it automatically subsetted the area of interest when I plotted the 'cyl' projection.  My guess is that was done via the basemap since that's the only place I specified the subsetted bounds.  Using the above I get the proper projection but it plots my entire global grid of data in one tiny area.  That is, I seem to have lost my automatic subsetting.

Comment: I don't see any cyl projection or subsetting in the question. Hence I'm lost what you are talking about.

Comment: I plotted the data no problem in 'cyl' using basemap to specify the subsetted area.  Of course this data was in lat/lon.  Using the above method for 'merc', the basemap no longer defines a subset.  Rather, the above plots the entire global data on one small map of Alaska.  Sorry if I'm not clear.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want me or anyone else to help you further the best would be to update the question with the new issue, namely showing a [mcve] of what is working using cyl and what is not working with merc. At the moment the problem is not clear to me, but if you show the example, I (or someone else) might have an idea.